# How to correctly set up a custom function in PXFormulaCombo Control?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I need some help regarding PXFormulaCombo Control.

1. How can I hide `Operation and Functions` Node In PXFormulaCombo Control?
2. Is it possible to override Validated Method? if yes, how do I get the value from Textbox above validate Button?

[Related Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NARJn.png)